# International conventions/standards for abbreviating large numbers?

Tags: localization, internationalisation, formatting

The concept of formatting large numbers in an abbreviated fashion for casual, non-scientific display (e.g. 12,345 as "12.3k") is well explored on SE:

- [What is an alternative way to display a very large number?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/23243/what-is-an-alternative-way-to-display-a-very-large-number)
- [Representing large numbers](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/39306/representing-large-numbers)
- [Java: Format number in millions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529432/java-format-number-in-millions)

But none of these address internationalization & localization.  Are there different standards for how to do this for other languages or locales?  Especially:

1. Are there different suffixes for different languages?
2. How is this done differently for numbering systems with different grouping rules (e.g. [China, Japan, India](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Digit_grouping))?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There absolutely are different standards on giving large numbers in a short format.

Not a very human-friendly resource, but one developed for software developers, is the Common Locale Data Repository from the Unicode organization. They have all sorts of data for displaying things like numbers and dates in different locales (not just languages but regional variations of languages as well, as UK and US English may differ, for example). They have these files that outline [how to format numbers in short ways](http://cldr.unicode.org/translation/number-patterns#TOC-Short-Numbers).

If you [go to their respository](http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr-aux/json/22.1/main/) and open the file for the language you want, and you search through for "`decimalFormats-numberSystem-latn`", you'll find the short section that specifies how to format numbers in that language.

So, here's [what you find for 'en_GB' (English for the UK)](http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr-aux/json/22.1/main/en_GB.json):

```
  "short": {
    "decimalFormat": {
      "1000-count-one": "0K",
      "1000-count-other": "0K",
      "10000-count-one": "00K",
      "10000-count-other": "00K",
      "100000-count-one": "000K",
      "100000-count-other": "000K",
      "1000000-count-one": "0M",
      "1000000-count-other": "0M",
      "10000000-count-one": "00M",
      "10000000-count-other": "00M",
      "100000000-count-one": "000M",
      "100000000-count-other": "000M",
      "1000000000-count-one": "0B",
      "1000000000-count-other": "0B",
      "10000000000-count-one": "00B",
      "10000000000-count-other": "00B",
      "100000000000-count-one": "000B",
      "100000000000-count-other": "000B",
      "1000000000000-count-one": "0T",
      "1000000000000-count-other": "0T",
      "10000000000000-count-one": "00T",
      "10000000000000-count-other": "00T",
      "100000000000000-count-one": "000T",
      "100000000000000-count-other": "000T"
    }
```

Looking at [the 'ja' file (for Japanese)](http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr-aux/json/22.1/main/ja.json), you get something different:

```
  "short": {
    "decimalFormat": {
      "1000-count-other": "0千",
      "10000-count-other": "0万",
      "100000-count-other": "00万",
      "1000000-count-other": "000万",
      "10000000-count-other": "0000万",
      "100000000-count-other": "0億",
      "1000000000-count-other": "00億",
      "10000000000-count-other": "000億",
      "100000000000-count-other": "0000億",
      "1000000000000-count-other": "0兆",
      "10000000000000-count-other": "00兆",
      "100000000000000-count-other": "000兆"
    }
```

(If you see weird characters like `å…†` when you open it in your browser, you want to make sure you set your browser to show the file encoding as 'Unicode'.)

... It's not the most elegant solution, but it should help you find what you're looking for.

Comment: This is awesome.  Now if only I knew of a library that knows how to leverage this... maybe ICU?

Comment: Looks like in ICU4J there's a (CompactDecimalFormat class)[http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/CompactDecimalFormat.html]. Hope that helps!

Comment: Interestingly, the standard doesn't seem to talk about how to handle negative numbers; and CompactDecimalFormat does not support them either. Any advice?

Comment: and it doesn't seem to clearly support currency formatting either.

Comment: [CLDR documentation](http://cldr.unicode.org/translation/number-patterns) says "If your language uses different formats for negative numbers than just adding "-" at the front, you can put in two patterns, separated by a semicolon. The first will be used for zero and positive values, while the second will be used for negative values." We see this in `currentyFormat` in English, for instance, gives `"pattern": "¤#,##0.00;(¤#,##0.00)"`, tells you the currency sign comes before and negatives are written in parentheses).

Comment: As for adding currencies to your short numbers, what you may want is to use is `"unitPattern-count-one"` and `"unitPattern-count-other"`, which in English gives `"{0} {1}"`. You can replace `{0}` with your number and `{1}` with your unit, and conceivably in another language where the order is inverted (`{1} {0}`; I haven't found any in practice) they would invert for you.

Comment: Updated link to ICU project's Compact Decimal Format docs: https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/dev/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/CompactDecimalFormat.html